# Closure Scope not captured? — Coffeescript

Tags: scope, coffeescript

Okay, I don't know how to phrase the title for this question.

```
openDir = (path) ->
socket.emit "get_metadata", path, (data) ->
    columnBox = $ "<div/>", class: "columnbox"
    for item in data.contents
        itemBox = $ "<div/>", class: "itembox"
        itemBox.click ->
            columnBox_inner.children().removeClass "selected"
            itemBox.addClass "selected" # <<<--- Over here
            openDir item.path
        columnBox.append itemBox
    columnBox.appendTo "#columnscontainer"
```

I understand that the variable `itemBox` is defined under `openDir`'s scope here. But since the pointed out line is in a lambda function, shouldn't `itemBox` there capture the object referenced by `itemBox` of the parent scope instead of getting mutated to the last object referenced by it?

To put it clearly, I expect the click handler of each `itemBox` to perform `addClass "selected"` to itself. But what happens is that `itemBox` in each of the click handlers always refer to the last itemBox.

I can easily fix this by changing where itemBox gets declared. i.e. changing

```
for item in data.contents
```

into

```
data.contents.forEach (item) ->
```

But I'd like to know why the lambda function does not capture the variables current value.

Comment: The question also applies to the `item` variable referenced in the `openDir item.path` line as even that gets defined in `openDir`'s scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This loop:

```
for item in data.contents
    itemBox = $ "<div/>", class: "itembox"
```

is somewhat deceptive if you're not used to (Coffee|Java)Script scope. The scoping actually looks more like this:

```
itemBox = undefined
for item in data.contents
    itemBox = $ "<div/>", class: "itembox"
```

so there is only one `itemBox` variable and that same variable gets used by each iteration of the loop. The click handler keeps a reference to `itemBox` but doesn't evaluate the variable until the click handler is called so all the handlers end up with the same `itemBox` value and that will be the `itemBox` value at the end of the loop.

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

So you could do this:

```
for item in data.contents
    do (item) ->
        # As before...
```

to get your `itemBox` scoped to each iteration of the loop individually.

Using `forEach`:

```
data.contents.forEach (item) ->
```

instead of a simple loop works because you're effectively using a function as the loop's body and any variables inside that function will be scoped to that function.

Comment: I knew about the scope part. But what you mentioned, 'The click handler keeps a reference to `itemBox` but **doesn't evaluate the variable until the click handler is called**', is what I didn't know. I had assumed that the reference to the  object pointed to by the variable was kept by the click handler. Thanks!