# Async.parallel with an array of tasks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript

I am having an issue figuring out how to make an array of functions with different parameters.  I am using coffeescript and [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) but I think it is a problem with my understanding of javascript.

I want to create an array of functions with different tasks.

```
names = ['Jeff', 'Maria', 'Steve']
tasks = []

for name in names
  tasks.push (callback)=>
      @controller.get_person name, (person) =>
        callback(null, person)

async.parallel(tasks, cb)
```

The problem is that the task is getting called with Steve (always the one that is last in the array) three times.  How do I make it so that there is one task per each name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closure Scope not captured? — Coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996218/closure-scope-not-captured-coffeescript)

Comment: @Bergi offers a general JavaScript solution that will also apply to CoffeeScript, my duplicate includes the CoffeeScript-specific `do` keyword. Take your pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in this particular case, you should probably make use of async's [`map`](https://github.com/caolan/async/#map):

```
getPerson = (name, callback) =>
  @controller.get_person name, (person) ->
    callback(null, person)

async.map names, getPerson, (err, persons) ->
  // Do stuff with persons
```

Note that if your `@controller.get_person` method followed the node practice of passing any errors as the first parameter to the callback, this would suffice:

```
async.map names, @controller.get_person, (err, persons) ->
  // Do stuff with persons
```

Something to keep in mind, perhaps.

Comment: very nice! Thank you.  The first way works beautifully.  The second way looks awesome.  However, in the second way, the `@controller` does not seem to get passed through to the `map` function.  What I mean by this is that the @ seems to get rebound and looses the reference to `controller`.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Scoop: Yes, you need to declare `get_person` with the fat arrow (`=>`) so it will always be bound to the object (in the class definition of whatever `@controller` is).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `for name in names` to `names.forEach (name)=>`. Be careful of the space after `forEach`.

```
names = ['Jeff', 'Maria', 'Steve']
tasks = []

names.forEach (name)=>
  tasks.push (callback)=>
      @controller.get_person name, (person) =>
        callback(null, person)

async.parallel(tasks, cb)
```