# how to use promise for loop in my case

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, coffeescript, promise

i fail to use promise in for loop. I need successively getting completion of reqWithPromise method

```
getUserInfoById: () ->
  ids = [196658162, 244668541, 84634196, 1234567, 45367181]
  last = Promise.resolve()
  for id of ids
    id = ids[id]
    url = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?fields=photo,status&user_ids=#{id}&access_token=#{atom.config.get('vk-messenger.apiToken')}&v=5.60"
    last = last.then(() -> reqWithPromise(url));

reqWithPromise = (url) ->
  https.get url, (@response) ->
    @response.on 'data', (chunk) ->
      @userModel = JSON.parse(chunk)['response'][0]
      console.log @userModel.id + ' ' + @userModel.first_name
```

i got

```
 5 times: 45367181 Daniil
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closure Scope not captured? — Coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996218/closure-scope-not-captured-coffeescript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and promises to get your calls to be processed sequentially:

```
getUserInfoById: () ->
  ids = [196658162, 244668541, 84634196, 1234567, 45367181]
  ids.reduce((memo, id)->
    # Check that the previous promise is resolved
    memo.then ->
      url = "https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?fields=photo,status&user_ids=#{id}&access_token=#{atom.config.get('vk-messenger.apiToken')}&v=5.60"
      # Call next promise func.
      reqWithPromise(url)
  , Q()) #First memo value is a promise

reqWithPromise = (url) ->
  # should return a promise
  deferred = Q.defer()
  https.get url, (@response) ->
    @response.on 'data', (chunk) ->
      @userModel = JSON.parse(chunk)['response'][0]
      console.log @userModel.id + ' ' + @userModel.first_name
      deferred.resolve(@userModel)
  deferred.promise
```